# How do I make a pop-up input box in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I have some code that needs to be updated. Inside of that code I want to get text input from a user.

What @-formula should be used to get text-input from a Lotus user ?

Comment: Hi. Marko. Please rewrite your question and add relevant code to the body of your question. No one here will download and inspect rar-archives.

Comment: and consult this tutorial, how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've done a couple of changes, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's  `[OkCancelEdit]` key available for `@Prompt` function. It brings up a simple input-box dialog.

To input short text from the keyboard, consider the following formula code:

```
REM "Receiving the text from the keyboard";
_enteredText:=@Prompt([OkCancelEdit] ; "Information request" ; "Enter your recommendation:"; "");

REM "Just to check, what we have typed";
@Prompt([OK]; "debug"; _enteredText);
```

I have created a simple button to demonstrate the code behaviour. check the pictures below:

[image: input text]

And when a user has accepted the input box:

[image: just for debug]

In case you need to add a large piece of text, consider making a dialog box.

Create a form for dialog and use [`@DialogBox` formula command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX.html).

You can find all relevant information in Domino Designer Help. When you are in Domino Designer, press `F1`, or select from menu `Help - Help Contents`

Comment: Thak you very much, i will try to implement your solution on my existing code tomorrow at work (just there I have Lotus). I shall return with the results. But, in main lines, it is excatly what i wanted to do. :)

Comment: @Marko I have edited your question and tags, to leave information relevant to the question subject.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to keep this in mind, next time!

Comment: It works, i have edited it a little.
Now i noticed that anyone who receives the button in mail cand edit it and save changes. Is there any option wich I can use to lock the code, or the editing mode for the other users?

Comment: Use [roles in notes database ACL](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_USING_ROLES_IN_A_DATABASE_ACL_OVERVIEW.html) and [@UserRoles](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_USERROLES.html) formula to separate simple users from those who can do some special things.

Comment: @Marko also, consider hiding the button from users who should not see this button. In the button properties open "Hide formula" tab and specify a formula to control the visibility of this button. If it is not an action button, but a button located inside of the document, then remember that hiding formula **hides the paragraph**, not the single object.

Comment: I can not enter in ACL database, it seems that i need Manager access. :(

I dont have @UserRoles as a command either. :(

I saw though something with ViewOnly at commands and something like UserAcces() at functions. Are they any good?

Comment: If you are actually sending the button in the rich text body of an email, then there is nothing you can do to lock it down. Instead, you should consider emailing a link to a database that contains a form that has the button on it. You can lock that database down as tightly as you need to.

Comment: I'll talk to my supervisor to grant me rights to do that. Thank you all for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you send a button via email, you essentially turn over the code to the end user. You don't say what you're doing with the button or why you're prompting the user for input but I'd suggest the following.
This assumes you just want answers to a question.
Create a db to store answers.
Send an email that includes a link to the 'answers' db.
The db postOpen event can either spawn a doc with an input field or spin up a LS driven input box. The user fills in the box and the LS creates a doc in the Answers db.
This isolates the design from the user and saves data/docs where you actually need the info.
If you need the data in some existing app, just modify the concept